# Unable to login to GitHub account even with correct credentials

Tags: authentication, github, passwords, usernametoken

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lPHEV.png)

I am unable to login to my GitHub account even with the correct username and password. They keeps telling me that username or password is not correct while it is the correct credentials. Please I need help on how to resolve it as you can see in the screen short. Thanks

Answer (score -3, accepted):

the problem with this is that you need to use a personal token access and this will solve your problem. try this link and see if it solves your problem https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kHkQnuYzwoo&t=309s

Comment: This instruction says logit into your account, but this is exactly what cannot be done.

Answer (score 0):

If you are okay to reset the password, click on the forgot password and reset it through the mail received from the github.

Comment: I have done that several times but still not working, they keep telling me this "Unable to verify your captcha response. Please visit https://docs.github.com/articles/troubleshooting-connectivity-problems/#troubleshooting-the-captcha for troubleshooting information".

Comment: I also suddenly couldn't login in to one of my accounts, though had no issues with any captcha. I did 2 resets that went through and right after Github claimed they were the wrong credentials. I tried both with email and account name. Turned out I had changed my account name and forgot it.